# Non-existent foreign key doesn't cause error in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

The following code should IMO produce an error because the `user_id=1` doesn't exist. Why does it work?

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id int PRIMARY KEY,
email text UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE claimed (
account_id int PRIMARY KEY,
user_id int,
domain text,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (user_id)
);

INSERT INTO claimed
(user_id, domain)
VALUES (1, "abcd");
```

Comment: You really want `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` columns, btw. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: @Shawn aren't INTEGER and INT the same for SQL? https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity

Comment: Not when it comes to sqlite and primary key columns. Read that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the relevant documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html):

> In order to use foreign key constraints in SQLite, the library must be compiled with neither `SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY` or `SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER` defined. If `SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER` is defined but `SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY` is not, then SQLite behaves as it did prior to version 3.6.19 (2009-10-14) - foreign key definitions are parsed and may be queried using `PRAGMA foreign_key_list`, but foreign key constraints are not enforced.

and:

> Foreign key constraints are disabled by default (for backwards compatibility), so must be enabled separately for each database connection.

and:

> Assuming the library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled, it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the `PRAGMA foreign_keys` command. For example:
>
> `sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`

Apparently you should use `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` at the top of your connection, and potentially rebuild with the appropriate options (though if you installed from package then I would personally assume that this has been done).

<sub>**Source:** Google `sqlite foreign key`, first result</sub>