# Enforcing referential integrity in a SQLite database using Node

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, graphql

I am using the package [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) in a node/graphql app. I have created some tables and one of them includes foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'StudentTakesCourse' ( 
    'studentId' INTEGER, 
    'courseId' INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY ('studentId', 'courseId'),
    FOREIGN KEY ('courseId') REFERENCES 'Courses' ('courseId') ON DELETE CASCADE, 
    FOREIGN KEY ('studentId') REFERENCES 'Students' ('studentId') ON DELETE CASCADE 
);
```

When I use 'DB Browser for SQLite' to interact with the database that gets created I get an error message when I attempt to violate referential integrity by putting a bad studentId or courseId in this join table. However, when I run this code that executes an insert into the join table:

```
async function addStudentToCourse(parent, args, context, info) {
    try {
        await context.db.addStudentToCourse(args.studentId, args.courseId);    
    } catch(err) {
        throw err;
    }

    return null;
}
```

with bad values no exception is thrown and the bad values are stored in the database. How do I ensure that an exception is thrown when violating referential integrity? I installed the package with a straight `> npm add sqlite3`

Comment: Read https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html especially the second section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non-existent foreign key doesn't cause error in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369602/non-existent-foreign-key-doesnt-cause-error-in-sqlite)

Comment: Ok, yes, I see its a compile issue. Since I am getting the sqlite library from npm is there any way to enable it in the existing package without compiling from source?